# Get a single object from a collection

Tags: javascript

This is the collection im getting:

```
    Collection {
  '313413509125898240' => MessageAttachment {
  message:
   Message {
     channel: [Object],
     id: '313413509616500736',
     type: 'DEFAULT',
     content: '',
     author: [Object],
     member: [Object],
     pinned: false,
     tts: false,
     nonce: null,
     system: false,
     embeds: [],
     attachments: [Circular],
     createdTimestamp: 1494794003634,
     editedTimestamp: null,
     reactions: Collection {},
     mentions: [Object],
     webhookID: null,
     hit: null,
     _edits: [] },
  id: '313413509125898240',
  filename: 'eJwFwdENhCAMANBdGIC2oIhuQ5BUcgqE9r4ut7vv_cx33uYwl-qQA-Cskvs8rWifiYvl3vkuaVSxuT-QVFO-ntJUwOMe3UbeIVLc.png',
  filesize: 8217,
  url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/305909472486883330/313413509125898240/eJwFwdENhCAMANBdGIC2oIhuQ5BUcgqE9r4ut7vv_cx33uYwl-qQA-Cskvs8rWifiYvl3vkuaVSxuT-QVFO-ntJUwOMe3UbeIVLc.png',
  proxyURL: 'https://images.discordapp.net/.eJwFwdtugjAYAOB34R5a-MtsvUOiC8ZDiIPFq6UrXSEixZ4wMb77vu8VeTNG66h3brZrhLrBCm26xDptuJKJ0lqNks-DTYS-I-4cF_1dTs4iwDnDjKwyQj8oBQCMIAWSQo5ZmuWU0YxgJPfLbum2p74sjsVp031WZaar3tf5phHqsWWGeLcK4Uc8Afx1GeNHXcSlvQVLzffwN1zDCOHmeXt5-q-4bnfneH
L7ZjkfJTS_smoPIpknFb3_AUVEQmA.36y13a_Z5MKnziL-pVQy3r_E_LU',
  height: 112,
  width: 112 } }
```

I want to console.log() the URL Section of that ONLY. But can't find anywhere that clearly states how to do this

Comment: Try

    console.log(Collection['313413509125898240'].url);

This should do the job.

I assume that `Collection` is the name of the variable holding the associative array that you've mentioned in your question

Answer (score 0):

console.log(Collection.url)

I think this should work

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: client.on('message', msg => {
  console.log(msg.attachments)
})

Comment: Try msg.url maybe?

Comment: Nope, because attachments returns a collection of what I posted in the original question. I need a way of getting the URL from msg.attachments's collection

Comment: Hmmm btw I am not on pc but does msg.attachments.collection or msg.attachments.url print anything

Comment: Both return undefined

Comment: What does msg.collections.message return and msg?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Comment: Wait sorry i ment msg.attachments.message

Comment: returned undefined

Comment: What does msg return

Comment: https://hastebin.com/axeyayicoq.coffeescript

Comment: Does msg.attachments.id return anything?

Comment: returns undefined

Comment: msg.id does this return anything?

Comment: 313421930097147914 - the message ID

Comment: Wait cant I just join ur discord xD, how about msg.author.id

Comment: http://discord.cat lmao - would be a lot easier :'D